# Cake PHP Fatal Error (256)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-bake

I have just created an application using cake bake and when I run it I get the screen that says `'Sweet, myApp got baked'` but there are no styling on it and at the bottom I get the following error:

```
Fatal Error (256): ConnectionManager::getDataSource - Non-existent data source default [CORE\cake\libs\model\connection_manager.php, line 102]
```

I've configure my database and user etc. But I don't understood what's going on.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Please visit http://frogfry.com/blog/cakephp-cannot-find-a-database-configuration-array-error

Answer (score 7):

You likely entered a name for Cake's bake wizard.
Replace that name in app/config/database.php with "$default"
Thus,

```
var $blog = array(...);
```

becomes

```
var $default = array(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

I've just fixed similar bug on my site. Check if all tables in the DB are there. My problem was missing table after db import . Good luck :)