# ConnectionManager::getDataSource - Non-existent data source

Tags: php, cakephp

> Fatal Error (256): ConnectionManager::getDataSource - Non-existent data source  [CORE/cake/libs/model/connection_manager.php, line 113]

I am getting the above error even though my default `$default` variables are present in `database.php`

Comment: which controller? Can you paste the content from `database.php` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cake PHP Fatal Error (256)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245417/cake-php-fatal-error-256)